# Web usage mining with rapidminer

Tags: rapidminer

I'm very much new to Rapid Miner and I'm currently doing a research on web usage mining. I want to analyze some apache and IIS web server logs and detect some fraudulent activities. I have googled and couldn't find some tutorials for this kind of web log file mining using Rapid Miner? 
So my questions:

```
1) Is it possible to do this with Rapid Miner(As I know it has a web mining extension)
2) Can somebody please advice me how to do this?some tutorials etc.
```

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score -1):

This was asked in the [rapidforum](http://rapid-i.com/rapidforum/index.php?topic=1368.0):

> yes, the RapidMiner 4.6 Community Edition together with its text mining plugin are suitable for web usage mining. The RapidMiner 4.6 operator LogFileSource allows to directly import web server log files. RapidMiner supports aggregations of web usage statistics, automated web page visitor session extraction, search robot filtering, mash-ups with web services to map ip addresses to countries, cities, and map coordinates, automated clustering of visits and/or click paths, frequent path item set mining and association rule generation, 2D and 3D visualization of web usage statistics, click path sequence analysis, personalized product recommendations for cross-selling, and many other things.